# how to get background image present in other folder with css?

Tags: css

Guys this is my folder structure

Project

index.php
css

style.css

js

javascript.js

image

background.jpeg

style.css

```
body{
background-image: url("image\background.jpeg");
}
```

index.php

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Todo Application</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id = "header">
    hiuiiiii
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

So guys tell me where am i wrong such that i can correct it so that my background image is displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is the issue.

**Incorrect** - `url("image\background.jpeg");`

**Correct** - `url("../image/background.jpg");`

`../` - This means one directory up to give the image location, as in your case, it is inside image directory.

Comment: Ok! Thanks a lot!  It has helped me :)

Answer (score 1):

change `background-image: url("image\background.jpeg");` to `background-image: url("../image/background.jpeg");`